# How to deal with long legend labels in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am working on a sectoral comparison of a stock index and I want to show correlation of employee numbers and profit, sales etc. However when I try to make a scatter plot with colors differing by sectors and add a legend, because that sector names are so long, plot becomes unreadable. I can make it work around with faceting but I want to show all sectoral data in one plot to make it easy to compare.

Here is the toy data frame

```
structure(list(Dates = c("2021-12-31", "2021-12-31", "2021-12-31", 
"2021-12-31", "2021-12-31", "2021-12-31", "2021-12-31", "2021-12-31", 
"2021-12-31", "2021-12-31", "2021-12-31", "2021-12-31", "2021-12-31", 
"2021-12-31", "2021-12-31"), Firm = c("BRYAT", "ZRGYO", "KONTR", 
"TRGYO", "DAPGM", "INVES", "ECZYT", "GWIND", "KMPUR", "SNGYO", 
"BERA", "ISGYO", "ALKA", "YGGYO", "SRVGY"), Sector = c("FINANCIAL AND INSURANCE ACTIVITIES", 
"FINANCIAL AND INSURANCE ACTIVITIES", "INFORMATION AND COMMUNICATION", 
"REAL ESTATE ACTIVITIES", "REAL ESTATE ACTIVITIES", "FINANCIAL AND INSURANCE ACTIVITIES", 
"FINANCIAL AND INSURANCE ACTIVITIES", "MANUFACTURING", "MANUFACTURING", 
"REAL ESTATE ACTIVITIES", "MANUFACTURING", "REAL ESTATE ACTIVITIES", 
"MANUFACTURING", "FINANCIAL AND INSURANCE ACTIVITIES", "FINANCIAL AND INSURANCE ACTIVITIES"
), `Number of Employees` = c(9, 32, 226, 144, 138, 6, 3, 50, 
219, 194, 33, 69, 208, 138, 11), EBITDA = c(23.8137, 1113.5212, 
113.9684, 6517.373, 387.6152, 1624.0192, -7.8884, 420.6019, 280.8024, 
4648.4098, 752.1899, 153.6431, 138.7504, 194.0958, 144.2635), 
    `Profit Margin` = c(574.7712, 706.7635, 21.3576, 357.6667, 
    34.2274, 537.1883, 372.8143, 31.6373, 14.5637, 150.702, 17.7025, 
    48.8762, 26.2978, 252.0494, 162.3127), Sales = c(47.7833, 
    186.8011, 611.8077, 1483.729, 912.4001, 312.5418, 0, 540.2263, 
    2172.6885, 2123.4395, 4217.1842, 545.2598, 700.9869, 277.6963, 
    414.2354), `Market Cap` = c(10681.875, 11405.4966, 2474.0625, 
    3920, NA, NA, 5407.5, 3123.1821, NA, 3728.536, 3320.352, 
    2435.225, 859.425, 3386.88, 4695.6), `Personnel Expense (Millions)` = c(3.4716, 
    8.4842, 7.7846, 11.869, 14.3014, 1.1789, 0.4507, 17.2696, 
    55.9705, 25.5093, 308.7577, 20.0843, 33.358, 10.5289, 14.3268
    ), `Personnel Expense Per Employee` = c(385733.5556, 265130.0938, 
    34445.1726, 82423.6111, 103633.6739, 196478.3333, 150236.6667, 
    345392.94, 255573.0411, 131491.1082, 9356294.7879, 291076.971, 
    160374.9663, 76296.7319, 1302436.6364), `Price/Earnings` = c(38.8935, 
    7.8922, 18.934, 0.7387, NA, NA, 12.5925, 18.2735, NA, 1.1651, 
    4.4476, 9.1377, 4.6621, 4.6933, 6.9838)), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I tried to make legend text font size smaller but this time the legend becomes unreadable. I am pretty sure that I can wrap the text but I really couldn't find the code.

```
ggplot(dataset%>%
               filter(Dates %in% "2021-12-31" & `Number of Employees` < 250))+
        geom_point(aes(x = `Number of Employees`, y  = `Profit Margin`, color = Sector),show.legend = T)+
    lims(y = c(-100,200))+
    theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 6,hjust = 0.5,lineheight = 121))
```

Comment: Your `filter` reduces the data to 0 rows, did you instead mean `"2021-12-31"`?

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY yeah will fix it

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you move the legend to the bottom (or top) and set the number of rows:

```r
dataset %>%
  filter(Dates %in% "2021-12-31", `Number of Employees` < 250) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `Number of Employees`, y = `Profit Margin`)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Sector)) +
  lims(y = c(-100,200)) +
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(size = 6,hjust = 0.5, lineheight = 121), 
    legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(color = guide_legend(nrow = 2))
```

[image: ggplot2 with legend on the bottom, 2 rows]

Comment: It is great but my real data has 14 labels and still it is not readable. I will try to modify your answer.

Comment: You can always use `nrow=3` or `nrow=4` depending on your real data. I don't know that there's a magic wand to point at really-long-level-names to make it look awesome on plots.

Answer (score 2):

I looked at Hadley Wickham's GitHub and found `legend.key.size()` and `legend.key.width()` options.

```
dataset %>%
  filter(Dates %in% "2021-12-31", `Number of Employees` < 250) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `Number of Employees`, y = `Profit Margin`)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Sector)) +
  lims(y = c(-50,200)) +
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(size = 5,vjust = 0.1), 
    legend.position = "bottom",
    legend.key.width = unit(0.05, "cm"),
    legend.key.size = unit(0.1, "cm"))+
  guides(color = guide_legend(ncol  = 3, nrow = 5))
```

[image: legend here]

Comment: Ouch, I really need my small-print glasses for that one ... nice thought, though. Good to see that the suggestion to move the legend and show multiple rows is paying off.

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY it ain't the greatest but something :D

Answer (score 1):

The scales package provides `label_wrap()` to wrap long strings at natural breakpoints after a specified number of characters. In combination with r2evans' suggestions about legend positioning and formatting, you should be able to achieve readable text for many labels.

[image: Plot with example data]

```r
dataset %>%
  filter(Dates %in% "2021-12-31" & `Number of Employees` < 250) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `Number of Employees`, y = `Profit Margin`, color = Sector)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_colour_viridis_d(
    option = "turbo", end = 0.8,
    labels = scales::label_wrap(20),
    guide = guide_legend(nrow = 2)
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    legend.text = element_text(size = 7, hjust = 0.5), 
    legend.key.height = unit(10, "mm"), # increase this to space out the wrapped labels
    legend.position = "bottom" # might be more space down here, depends on plot dimensions
  )
```

14 distinct colours will be tricky, my suggestion for that is to use/abuse the turbo palette, as above, or consider using both shapes and colour to distinguish your categories.